# Add a new column with value from another column matching a pattern

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
COL1 COL2 
A    eucaryotes; mammal; carnivoridae; carnivorinae; carnivorus
B    viruses; Retroviridae
C    viruses; mononegavirales; Phenuiviridae; Ascovirinae; Reovirus
D    Unclassified; RNA virus
```

And I would like to parse the **COL2** column with element separated by `";"` and add a **COL3** column with the element containing **"viridae"** for each row.

I should then get:

```
COL1 COL2                                                           COL3
A    eucaryotes; mammal; carnivoridae; carnivorinae; carnivorus     carnivoridae
B    viruses; Retroviridae                                          Retroviridae
C    viruses; mononegavirales; Phenuiviridae; Ascovirinae; Reovirus Phenuiviridae
D    Unclassified; RNA virus                                        NA
```

Does someone have an idea please ?

Here is the dataframe in dict format if it can helps

```
{'COL1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}, 'COL2 ': {0: 'eucaryotes; mammal; carnivoridae; carnivorinae; carnivorus', 1: 'viruses; Retroviridae', 2: 'viruses; mononegavirales; Phenuiviridae; Ascovirinae; Reovirus', 3: 'Unclassified; RNA virus '}}
```

Comment: I have to ask, what about the first row? carnivoridae does not contain the -viridae ending. And your requirement is to have a word with that suffix in COL3

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = {'COL1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}, 'COL2': {0: 'eucaryotes; mammal; carnivoridae; carnivorinae; carnivorus', 1: 'viruses; Retroviridae', 2: 'viruses; mononegavirales; Phenuiviridae; Ascovirinae; Reovirus', 3: 'Unclassified; RNA virus '}}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

You can then use the following method: First tranform the column into a column of lists

```
df['COL2_list']= df['COL2'].str.split(';')
df = df.reset_index()
```

Then parse through every row of the df to find th strings you want (here I choose 'ridae'):

```
DF = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    a = df[df.index==i]
    b = [string for string in a['COL2_list'][i] if 'ridae' in string] 
    a = np.where(len(b)!=0, b,'NAN')
    DF.append(a)

DF = pd.DataFrame(DF, columns = ['COL3'])
DF
```

which gives you

```
 COL3
0    carnivoridae
1    Retroviridae
2   Phenuiviridae
3            None
```

and then concatenate the results:

```
Full = pd.concat([df,DF], axis=1)
```

which gives:

```
index COL1                                               COL2  \
0      0    A  eucaryotes; mammal; carnivoridae; carnivorinae...   
1      1    B                              viruses; Retroviridae   
2      2    C  viruses; mononegavirales; Phenuiviridae; Ascov...   
3      3    D                           Unclassified; RNA virus    

                                           COL2_list            COL3  
0  [eucaryotes,  mammal,  carnivoridae,  carnivor...    carnivoridae  
1                           [viruses,  Retroviridae]    Retroviridae  
2  [viruses,  mononegavirales,  Phenuiviridae,  A...   Phenuiviridae  
3                        [Unclassified,  RNA virus ]            None
```

Slightly different from what you wrote but it is because you didn't spell things right.

Answer (score 0):

To match your example:

```
df.assign(COL3=df['COL2'].str.extract('(\w+v[io]ridae)'))

  COL1                                               COL2           COL3
0    A  eucaryotes; mammal; carnivoridae; carnivorinae...   carnivoridae
1    B                              viruses; Retroviridae   Retroviridae
2    C  viruses; mononegavirales; Phenuiviridae; Ascov...  Phenuiviridae
3    D                            Unclassified; RNA virus            NaN
```

To match your stated requirement of finding words ending with viridae:

```
df.assign(COL3=df['COL2'].str.extract('(\w+viridae)'))

  COL1                                               COL2           COL3
0    A  eucaryotes; mammal; carnivoridae; carnivorinae...            NaN
1    B                              viruses; Retroviridae   Retroviridae
2    C  viruses; mononegavirales; Phenuiviridae; Ascov...  Phenuiviridae
3    D                            Unclassified; RNA virus            NaN
```